# Copy directory from GIT to TFS

Tags: git, tfs, migration

I want to move my project from  git directory to TFS. Any clue how to do it?
I have tried to move from Git Bash but couldnt do it. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean moving to TFSVC rather than TFS-git.

There is a series of blog posts about it using git-tf. Very simple to do I would think if you don't have any branches, existing releases etc.

Also, what is your motivation to move to TVSVC if it is what you are doing? TFS 2013 now supports git and moving to git is what the thrust of industry generally is these days.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move your local Git repo to TFS you should follow:

1. Create team project with Git as the source control type
2. Create a new Git repo within this team project to revive the source
3. On your local git repo add the TFS repo as an origin
4. Push to the new origin

All your code should now be in a Git repo inside of TFS.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes